# How can I build an application with Ruby on Rails 4 on a Windows 10 Pro computer when the command prompt has been disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning how to build an application with Ruby on Rails 4 by completing the step-by-step exercises in the third edition of the book "Beginning Rails 4". I do not own my own computer, so I went to the public library to use a computer there. After successfully installing Ruby 2.6.5-1 and opening the command prompt to begin to install the RVM and Rails I saw that the command prompt has been disabled on the computers at the library*. Is there another way for me to get Rails up and running so that I build my first application?

[*Screenshot of Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRWS.jpg)

Comment: Here's a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+cloud+ide) you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Powershell** as an alternative.

Powershell can be accessed by searching.

Simply type `win` in the search box on **taskbar**, and choose **Windows PowerShell** in the result.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: The system administrator at the library has disabled Windows PowerShell and Windows PowerShell (x86)*. I was able to open Windows PowerShell ISE and Windows PowerShell ISE (x86) and use the "ruby --version" command, but when I continued to the next step in my book (Beginning Rails 4) and attempted to update RubyGems and install Rails I received this error:
"gem : ERROR: SSL verification error at depth 1: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19)"
*https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BV0OWvYmJl6QUqMNInpiLVz8mVp805vD
**https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S3tMxQZ-XHOmrTduD7DADjVCNVAjY1md

Comment: I think the issue is with your Internet provider. There seems to be a problem with your SSL certificate.

If you've not been able to solve the problem maybe you could try connecting to another Internet provider.

Also, I would suggest that you try out **Rails 5** when you are done with the this Book, since you may face some issues down the road due to version compatibility.

Or try to look out for an updated version of the Book. I would also suggest "**The Rails 5 Way**" and "**Learn Rails**" by Michael Hartl as they are up-to-date with Rails version 5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've concluded that using Rails isn't possible from a computer at the library due to the issue with the SSL certificate.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I hope that this does not discourage your Ruby on Rails learning journey.